# Verifying if Mr and Mrs Ede travelling in late 19th century Japan were Cecil Zohrab Ede and Kogiku?

Tags: 19th-century, ship, japan

I have investigated about "C.Z. Ede" and I have some data.
For example, "Mr  and Mrs Ede" got on board a boat and a record of National Archives.

First "Mr and Mrs Ede" got on board a boat from Nagasaki to Yokohama in 1893.  Nagasaki and Yokohama are in Japan. But the ship from Japan to foreign country and from foreign country to Japan often called at Nagasaki in those days.

My great-grandmother (Kogiku) went abroad with her husband.　Mr Ede lived in Kobe.

It is interesting that "Mr and Mrs Ede" get on board a boat from Nagasaki to Yokohama, instead of boarding a boat from Nagasaki to Kobe.

I think railway wasn't complete from Nagasaki to Kobe.  So people who travelled from Kobe to Nagasaki had to walk on the way. People who had money used railway from Kobe to Yokohama, and used ship from Yokohama to Nagasaki.  This way was faster than directly from Kobe to Nagasaki.

And I think main office of Mr Ede's company (Jardine Matheson）was in Yokohama.
I think there is a possibility of calling at the office.

Even family name Ede is rare in Japan in our time.  There were not many  foreigners in Japan during the 1890s.  I think Ede of "Mr and Mrs Ede" was Cecil Zohrab Ede. I think this makes sense.

Next I got copy of records of national archives (http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C1948323).

This records contain Probate Records that say Cecil Zohrab Ede was a bachelor.
So, he left Japan 1899 or 1900 alone. My great-grandmother had sick parents so she could not leave Japan. She was a strong woman and the daughter of "samurai".  "Samurai" had to endure many things, so I think she chose to stay in Japan.

How can I determine if the Mr and Mrs Ede above were Cecil Zohrab Ede and my great grandmother Kogiku?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to try to find Mr Ede in the Japanese Household Registration Records (Koseki)?

Comment: At the moment it looks like you are trying to make some comments rather than asking a specific answerable question which is what we require within our focussed question and answer format.  I recommend that the [Tour] be reviewed because our format can take a little getting used to.  There is a question in your post that I have pulled out into a title - perhaps that is what we can focus on.

Comment: @akira When referencing a DNA test, can you please state at minimum what test you both did as just saying DNA is not very helpful. Please references this [Q&A for some tips] (http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/can-we-make-a-section-on-the-faq-for-dna-questions) on how to communicate DNA test info.

Comment: @CRSouser I'm thinking that we should keep DNA out of this particular question so that it can remain focussed on the paper record.

Comment: @PolyGeo Agreed, though he referenced DNA and he didn't provide details in this or his other question. I CC'n Comment to his other question